# Is there a way to track Wikipedia pages one has read already?

Tags: bookmarks, wikipedia

I read a lot of random Wikipedia articles for fun/help with schoolwork, but sometimes I feel like going back to articles I had read before to get a mental refresher.

Other than just saving wiki articles to my bookmarks, is there a way to track all the Wikipedia pages I have read already?

Answer (score 4):

You can add them to the watchlist by clicking on the star at the top near the search field or by using the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>. Then you can view them by visiting the [Edit raw watchlist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:EditWatchlist) page.

**Update:**
The latest (2021-10-05) official iOS app has a "Saved" feature which is exactly what one would expect (even separate lists).

Comment: I saw this one, but doesn't adding it to watchlist send you notifications whenever the page is modified? Having a "favourites" like how Youtube does would be ideal

Comment: I don't know, can't remember receiving emails from Wikipedia. And if I did, I probably disabled them. I'm currently using [Wikiwand](http://www.wikiwand.com) which has Facebook login and a bookmarks feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using firefox, use ctrl-h to bring up the history sidebar.

Click the "View" dropdown box and choose "By Site".  Click the + next to wikipedia.com to see the pages you have visited.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option. First register to Wikipedia (have user/password). Then enable book creator and add the relevant articles to your book/books.

Comment: is it the [Collection Creator](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&bookcmd=book_creator&referer=Main+Page) you're referring to?

Comment: Probably yes. But refer to Iulian Onofrei's answer. This was the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox, there is an extension called [Visited](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/visited/) that allows you to highlight links you have previously visited with a particular color. You could disable its automatic feature and just use it to highlight the links you choose with the shortcut.

There is not a similar extension for Chrome that I could find, however, you could use manual styling extensions to override the visited link color CSS if you wanted.